# Filtering + Grouping a DF on same sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a really weird behavior when using Pandas.loc and pandas.groupy on a same sentence on a big data frame. I´ve noticed this behavior after updating from pandas 1.5x to 2.0x

To illustrate.

This is the small dataframe. This DF has 3 mm rows
[image: small dataframe sample]

This is the big dataframe . This DF has 80 mm rows.
[image: big dataframe sample]

As you can see, they are similar. The small if a giftcards transactions dataframe. The big is a giftcards + affiliates + pre-paid cell phone transactions. they have the same structure as you can see on df.info()

[image: Small DF info]

[image: Big DF info]

but, this line of code works on the small dataframe and does not on the big dataframe

```
Extração = Unificado.loc[Unificado.data.dt.date <= date(2022,12,31)].groupby(Unificado.data.dt.to_period('Q')).aggregate({'gmv' : 'sum', 'receita':'sum', 'mci':'nunique'})
```

This is the output when it fails

```
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 Extração = Unificado.loc[Unificado.data.dt.date <= date(2022,12,31)].groupby(Unificado.data.dt.to_period('Q')).aggregate({'gmv' : 'sum', 'receita':'sum', 'mci':'nunique'})
      2 Extração

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8256, in DataFrame.groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, observed, dropna)
   8253     raise TypeError("You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'")
   8254 axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
-> 8256 return DataFrameGroupBy(
   8257     obj=self,
   8258     keys=by,
   8259     axis=axis,
   8260     level=level,
   8261     as_index=as_index,
   8262     sort=sort,
   8263     group_keys=group_keys,
   8264     observed=observed,
   8265     dropna=dropna,
   8266 )

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:931, in GroupBy.__init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, observed, dropna)
    928 self.dropna = dropna
    930 if grouper is None:
--> 931     grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
...
-> 4274     raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
   4275 else:
   4276     indexer, _ = self.get_indexer_non_unique(target)

ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

But, for my surprise, on the big dataframe, it does work as long I "break" my code in two lines :

```
Extração = Unificado.loc[Unificado.data.dt.date <= date(2022,12,31)]
Extração = Extração.groupby(Extração.data.dt.to_period('Q')).aggregate({'gmv' : 'sum', 'receita':'sum', 'mci':'nunique'})
```

Really lost here guys. What could have change to cause this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The images were just do easily show that both dadtaframes are similar. Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue is related to the dataframe index. When the small dataframes where concatenated, they kept their index, so there are some duplicated index.

So, just reseting the big dataframe index solved.